# "undefined reference to `sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance()'" when compiling mariadb's c ++ connector

Tags: c++, mariadb, qt5, connector

Hi guys I have a project in QT5 which must connect to a mariadb server using C ++, the problem is that when compiling with qmake it returns several undefined reference errors with everything related to :: sql.

```
:-1: error: main.o: in function `printContacts(std::shared_ptr<sql::Statement>&)':

../test_server/main.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'

../test_server/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `sql::operator<<(std::ostream&, sql::SQLString const&)'

:-1: error: main.o: in function `std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString>::~pair()':

/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:211: error: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'

:-1: error: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:211: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'

:-1: error: main.o: in function `std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString>::pair<char const (&) [5], char const (&) [8], true>(char const (&) [5], char const (&) [8])':
```

When compiling with g ++ directly from the console, it compiles without problems by passing the libraries as parameters, excluding the  library in the `main.cpp` file.

```
g++ -o test_server main.cpp -std=c++11 -lmariadbcpp
```

In the `.pro` file I have created the link to the mariadb libraries that I have installed without any problem.
`test_server.pro`.

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console

CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target


unix:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L/usr/lib64 -lmariadbcpp

unix {
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/mariadb -I..include
DEPENDPATH += /usr/include/mariadb -I..include
}
```

In the main function the following code: `main.cpp`

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <mariadb/conncpp.hpp>


void printContacts(std::shared_ptr<sql::Statement> &stmnt)
{
   try
   {
     std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(
            stmnt->executeQuery("SHOW DATABASES")
         );
      while (res->next())
      {
         std::cout << "- "
            << res->getString(1)
            << " "  << std::endl;
      }
   }
  catch (sql::SQLException& e)
   {
      std::cerr << "Error printing contacts: "
         << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    try
      {
        sql::Driver* driver = sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance();
        sql::SQLString url("jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/bt");
        sql::Properties properties({
              {"user", "mysuser"},
              {"password", "mypassword"}
           });
         std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> conn(driver->connect(url, properties));
         std::shared_ptr<sql::Statement> stmnt(conn->createStatement());
         printContacts(stmnt);
         conn->close();
      }
      catch (sql::SQLException &e)
      {
         std::cerr << "Error Connecting to MariaDB Platform: "
            << e.what() << std::endl;
         return 1;
      }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Build output

```
22:08:05: Running steps for project test_server...
22:08:05: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:08:05: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j4
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../test_server -I. -I/usr/include/mariadb -I-I..include -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/../lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../test_server/main.cpp
g++  -o test_server main.o   /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so -lpthread   
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `printContacts(std::shared_ptr<sql::Statement>&)':
/home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `sql::operator<<(std::ostream&, sql::SQLString const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
/home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/chls/Documentos/Mayoreo/Mayoreo/build-test_server-Desktop-Debug/../test_server/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString>::~pair()':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:211: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:211: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString>::pair<char const (&) [5], char const (&) [8], true>(char const (&) [5], char const (&) [8])':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:353: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:353: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:353: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString>::pair<char const (&) [9], char const (&) [11], true>(char const (&) [9], char const (&) [11])':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:353: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:353: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:353: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `std::less<sql::SQLString>::operator()(sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&) const':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_function.h:386: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::operator<(sql::SQLString const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString>::pair(std::pair<sql::SQLString const, sql::SQLString> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:314: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(sql::SQLString const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:314: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::SQLString(sql::SQLString const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:314: undefined reference to `sql::SQLString::~SQLString()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref._ZTIN3sql12SQLExceptionE[DW.ref._ZTIN3sql12SQLExceptionE]+0x0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for sql::SQLException'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:143: test_server] Error 1
22:08:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test_server (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
22:08:05: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Comment: Can you get a verbose build output, to see what commands are really executed, and most importantly what arguments are passed and in which order (because when linking order matters)?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include the build output. And format it like code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Ok i add it to a new answer

Comment: As for your problem, the command to link your application is `g++ -o test_server main.o /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so -lpthread` which means your `.pro` file is not configured correctly.

Comment: By the way `-I..include` is incorrect, perhaps you meant `../include`?

Comment: I want to compile with qmake from the qt5 interface and from qmake it doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, i could fix it.